# On angular 17 page refresh - firestore returns empty result

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Landing page -> list page.

When starting the app, open the list, the result of firestore is as expected. I can go back and forward again and it always loads correct data.

But, when I just hit enter on the url the firestore result is empty. No error, query in the log looks ok. It behaves like that on my shared host and local with MAMP. When I click back to the landing page and forward (on the button), data is loaded properly again.

When I start Angular with ng serve, data is loaded correctly even when I hit enter in the url!

Maybe firestore module is not loaded correctly? Any other ideas?

thx a lot,
Niko

```
  public getListings(businessKey: string | null, publishedOnly: boolean, locationId: number | null): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise(async (result) => {

      var ref = this.db.db.collection('/listing').ref.limit(100)

      try {
        if (locationId) {
          ref = ref.where("locationId", "==", locationId)
        }
        if (businessKey) {
          ref = ref.where("businessKey", "==", businessKey)
        }
        if (publishedOnly) {
          ref = ref.where("publish", "==", true)
        }

        var queryResult = await ref.get()
        console.log(queryResult.size) // is 0, so it seems to finish properly
        const resultData = queryResult?.docs.map(d =>
          ListingData.toListing(d.data()!, d.id)
        );
        result(resultData ?? []);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        result([])
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried building in dev and prod mode for all variations, no difference!
With ng serve it works, on MAMP or shared host it is not working.

Comment: I think it is a kind of security thing, since when I try to go automatically back and forward, even with a delay, it is not working, when I go automatically back and click forward it is working. I guess it is a "feature" to prevent automatic polling of data